VBA Outlook: Why does this assignment of a class variable work in runtime but not in step-through debug?
Can anyone explain this strange behavior of classes within each other?  An object becomes Nothing for no reason I can see, and only when stepping through the code slowly.  It becomes a runtime problem in the application from which I've isolated it, which has a lot more going on, and during which an object becomes Nothing (it happens if the object is a class as shown here or a standalone dictionary).
The simple code below runs perfectly unless I step through it slowly in debug as noted in the rems and below.  I hope an explanation of this simple case will help diagnose the problem in the busier application.
A standard module creates a class ClsSimpleAgent, which creates a class ClsSimpleBuffer, which collects data in a dictionary.  Then, the module passes the buffers to a class ClsSimpleScrubber that processes the data.  The problem lies within the function PushItem of ClsSimpleAgent where the private variable for the ClsSimpleBuffer does not persist - but, again, only when stepping through slowly (and presumably, when the larger application is churning on other work along its way).
Part of the weirdness is that, as best I can tell, when stepping either quickly or slowly, the private variable this.SimpleBuffer never changes from Nothing in the Locals window when in scope, but the Public Property SimpleBuffer in Locals populates as expected when in scope.  However, a watch for the private variable this.SimpleBuffer shows that it is populated when in context.
All my tests begin from a standard module procedure and the problem persists even if that module creates a class that runs the test code (which I thought might make a difference).  For simplicity, this example runs the test code from the standard module.
Standard Module
Sub simpletest()
Dim i as Integer
Dim agent As ClsSimpleAgent
Dim scrubber As ClsSimpleScrubber

    Set agent = New ClsSimpleAgent

    For i = 1 To 3
    
        agent.PushItem "test " & i
        
    Next i
    
    With New ClsSimpleScrubber: Set scrubber = .Create(agent.SimpleBuffer):  End With
    
    For i = 4 To 6
    
        agent.PushItem "test " & i
        
    Next i
    
    scrubber.PushBuffer agent.SimpleBuffer
    
    scrubber.Scrub
    
    Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub

Class ClsSimpleAgent
Option Explicit
Private Type Tbuffer
'I started with mSimpleBuffer instead of this Private Type - no difference
    SimpleBuffer As ClsSimpleBuffer
End Type

Private this As Tbuffer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Debug.Print "Start Agent up."

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()

    Debug.Print "Start Agent term."

End Sub

Public Function PushItem(ByVal itemval As String)

    'If I wait anywhere in this function during step through, this.SimpleBuffer acts like it's Nothing _
        if I don't wait, it fails the Is Nothing tests, even though Locals says it's Nothing
        
    If this.SimpleBuffer Is Nothing Then Set this.SimpleBuffer = New ClsSimpleBuffer

    If this.SimpleBuffer Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "this SimpleBuffer is nothing."

    this.SimpleBuffer.PushItem itemval

End Function

Public Property Get SimpleBuffer() As ClsSimpleBuffer

    Set SimpleBuffer = this.SimpleBuffer
    
    Set this.SimpleBuffer = Nothing

End Property

Class ClsSimpleBuffer
Private mBufferDict As Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Debug.Print "Buffer up."

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()

    Debug.Print "Buffer term."

End Sub

Public Function PushItem(ByVal itemval As String)

    If mBufferDict Is Nothing Then
    
        Set mBufferDict = New Dictionary
        
    End If
    
    mBufferDict.Add itemval, itemval

End Function

Public Property Get BufferDict() As Dictionary

    Set BufferDict = mBufferDict

End Property

Class ClsSimpleScrubber
Private mSimpleBuffer As ClsSimpleBuffer
Private mBufferColl As New Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Debug.Print "Scrubber up."

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()

    Debug.Print "Scrubber term."

End Sub

Public Function Create(ByRef bufferref As ClsSimpleBuffer)

    If bufferref Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "Scrub.Create gets nothing."
    
    Set mSimpleBuffer = bufferref
    
    mBufferColl.Add mSimpleBuffer
    
    Set Create = Me

End Function

Public Function PushBuffer(ByRef bufferref As ClsSimpleBuffer)

    mBufferColl.Add bufferref

End Function

Public Function Scrub()
Dim i as Integer
Dim buffer As ClsSimpleBuffer

    For Each buffer In mBufferColl
    
        Dim keyval As String: Dim keys As Variant
        
        keys = buffer.BufferDict.keys
        
        With buffer.BufferDict
        
            For i = 0 To .Count - 1
            
                Debug.Print "scrubbing " & .item(keys(i))
                
            Next i
        
        End With
    
    Next

End Function


What is the abbreviated code writing for? With New ClsSimpleScrubber: Set scrubber = .Create(agent.SimpleBuffer):  End With This is inconvenient for debugging.

@valnik:  I appreciate your time.  This continuous line is only for saving white space on easy factory method calls.
